# How to use my static IP outside the network?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, ip, static-ip

I want to use my static IP when I'm far away of my network / router. Like to make it portable. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Maybe through a vpn or proxy server? What's the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: So your ISP have given you a static IP? This is what identifies your home (or business) on the Internet... Don't confuse this with a static IP on a LAN... If you have a record of your public IP then you can connect to it from anywhere. Set up port forwarding or a VPN to the IP and whatever you need to connect to will work. A VPN is by far the most secure but you need to configure them and not all "public" access locations (such as cafes, libraries etc.) Allow vpn ports...

Comment: If you have a static IP issued by your ISP, simply buy a domain name and configure it to point to your IP address, or get a free subdomain from [No-IP](http://freedns.no-ip.com/). If your IP is not static (dynamic), then use No-IP or a similar dynamic DNS service all the same.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion VPN is best solution.

1. Make sure if VPN server can work on your internet connection (at home). Some providers may have routers without [VPN Passthrough](http://www.tp-link.us/article/?faqid=558) and VPN server cannot work behind that kind of router. It's very rare to see router without it used by internet provider.
2. Buy VPN router (if you dont have it).
3. Configure your VPN on router (this may be more or less complicated, some routers have simple creators for VPN configurations)
4. Configure your VPN on device (laptop?), use static IP inside VPN network or configure router to assign same IP
5. Configure port redirection on router. You can use only port redirections, you cannot use whole IP because it must handle VPN incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is access your PC from a remote location then I suggest TeamViewer http://www.teamviewer.com - works on Windows, OSX, iOS and Android - free for commercial use. I am not affiliated with TeamViewer; I am a satisfied customer.

You do not have any guarantee that your modems IP address will not change unless your ISP provides that guarantee (usually only if you pay more). That said it "tends" to stay the same for long periods of time. You can use port forwarding to a SINGLE machine on your network to do what you asked. It is kind of a pain but not overly complex (Kamil's answer addresses this). Repost if you want to know more about this (it would be helpful to know what kind of router and modem you have as well as your ISP).

Comment: I think he wants more than remote desktop.

Comment: If so then you had a great answer. But if he does just want remote access then TV is much simpler than port forwarding and certainly less expensive than a new router.

Comment: I understand your idea now. However - computer at home must be turned on. We don't know why and how he wants to use home ip remotely, I didn't voted down your question, I just commented.

Comment: TeamViewer is NOT FREE for commercial use.